# Map JSON payload to DTO with different field names

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I have a simple GitHub payload incoming to my ASP.NET Core application and I would like to know how can I map the payload I receive to my DTO.

Example DTO

```
public class GithubPayload
{
    public string Action { get; set; }  // action
    public string Name { get; set; }    // pull_request.title
}
```

Example payload

```
{
  "action": "deleted",
  "pull_request": {
    "title": "Fix button"
  }
}
```

Comment: JsonProperty attribute on action and a custom converter on the Name. check Json.Net

Comment: Yeah,  that's what I need, too bad it doesn't work with nested properties but still better than nothing. Thanks

Comment: You can write one yourself that works with nested properties

Comment: Of course I can :) Can you answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `JsonProperty` attribute on `Action` and a custom converter on the Name that can interpret nested properties. check Json.Net's `JsonConverter`

```
public class GithubPayload {
    [JsonProperty("action")]
    public string Action { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(NestedConverter), "pull_request.title")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Where `NestedConverter` is a custom `JsonConverter` that will read a nested property

```
public class NestedConverter : JsonConverter {
    private readonly string path;

    public NestedConverter (string path) {
        this.path = path; 
    }

    //...to do
}
```

### Update:

Using a JsonConverter for converting the payload itself actually  works as well

```
public class GithubPayloadConverter : JsonConverter {

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) {
        return objectType == typeof(GithubPayload);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        dynamic data = JObject.Load(reader);
        var model = new GithubPayload {
            Action = data.action,
            Name = data.pull_request.title
        };
        return model;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and decorating the class itself

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(GithubPayloadConverter))]
public class GithubPayload {
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialization is simply

```
string json = @"{ 'action': 'deleted', 'pull_request': { 'title': 'Fix button' } }";

var payload = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GithubPayload>(json);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just an idea:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public class GithubPayload
        {
            public string Action { get; set; }  // action
            public string Name { get; set; }    // pull_request.title
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string json = @"{
  ""action"": ""deleted"",
  ""pull_request"": {
                ""title"": ""Fix button""
  }
        }";

            dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

            GithubPayload entity = new GithubPayload();
            entity.Action = obj.action;
            entity.Name = obj.pull_request.title;

            ..................
        }
    }
}
```

Tested this solution, it works.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking more in terms of attribute filters e.g. `[JsonName("action")]` on top of my field. Of course if that doesn't exist I will have to do with this solution.